# Google Play does not accept android app bundle signed by another PC

Tags: android-studio, google-play, sha1, android-keystore

The app bundle was generated by the first PC (Ubuntu 18.04) using keystore and its password. Google Play accepted app bundle and application was updated successfully.

After that same process was repeated in another PC (same project, same keystore, same password) and successfully generated app bundle. But Google Play did not accept it and showing error:

> App bundle was signed with wrong key. Choose appropriate key: SHA1: C9:AF....

I tried different ways to solve this problem:

1. Tried to create app bundle on Windows and MacOS machine. Could not try on Linux machine because there are no Linux machine available
2. Besides the app bundle trying to create the apk which was generated successfully, but when uploading Google Play showed error: signature is invalid

Developer who owns Linux machine is leaving project and we need to generate app bundle in another machine.

What is the reason for this problem if app bundle is created by same keystore and password? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure even though you think it is being signed with the same keystore, you have made a mistake somewhere. You can check this for yourself though. App Bundles are just signed using the same scheme as jarsigner. So you can print them using keytool.

`keytool -list -printcert -jarfile mybundle`

If the values are the same for the bundles produced on both PCs then they are signed with the same key in the same keystore. Otherwise you are doing something wrong. Maybe using a release key on one, and a debug key on another, or the keystore has two different keys with different names. Or maybe you think you are using the keystore when you aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Google play accept the apk generated by same keystore file. So please check you have made some mistake. Use the previous keystore and compare it with the current one to check and verify the SHA! and SHA256  Signature

Answer (score -2):

if upload an Application on play-store with one Keystore you don't need to create another keystore for the same project, just use the same keystore for your next version uploading.

NOTE: Google not allow to create multiple keystore for same project.

> Remember the selection of signature of version what you selected. this must be the same for your next release.

[image]

Comment: Read the content of the first parenthesis in the second paragraph - it's the same keystore

Comment: New keystore has not been generated. Similar keystore is being used.